# Changing all occurrences NaN in each dataframe in a list of dataframes to another value

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a simple function that changes all occurences of NA to "-" see below. However when I try to apply the same rational to NaN (not a number) i get an error.  I am wondering what is so special about NaN that prevents me from doing the same

```
NoNA <- function(x,...){
  x[is.na(x)] <- "-"
  return(x)
  }


map(df,NoNA)
```

works as I want

however the following

```
NoNaN <- function(x,...){
  x[is.nan(x)] <- "-"
  return(x)
  }


map(df,NoNaN)
```

provides me with the following error.

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.nan, value = "-") :
anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'builtin'

why is the same not possible with NaN and how do I get around it?

Comment: Probably a typo : `x[is.nan(x)] <- "-"` and not `x[is.nan] <- "-"`. Btw, `NoNA` function should also work for `NaN` values.

Comment: @Ronak Shah yes there was a typo but it still didn't work but different message Error in is.nan(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list' and my noNA does not change NaN

Comment: I also get the same issue with inf

Comment: Maybe an example data would help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes being made here.

1. `base::is.nan` is written for vectors, not frames. The reason your `NoNA` fails is that it is being passed the frame as a whole. We need a way to apply the function to each column individually.
2. Whether you use `purrr::map` or `lapply`, `lapply(x, NoNA)` should work just fine. The only gotcha is that it returns a `list`, so in order to preserve the `data.frame`-class of `x`, you can use a small trick:

   ```r
   # equivalent
   x[] <- map(x, NoNA)
   x[] <- lapply(x, NoNA)
   ```

   The reason this works is that the `[<-` assignment function is working on just one component of `x` at a time, so does not change the class of `x` as a whole. Since a `data.frame` is really just a `list` where each element is the same length (plus an attribute or two), this works well.
3. I'm going to assume that the `NaN` you're finding are in columns that are either `integer` or `numeric`. By replacing your `NaN`s with `'-'`, you are forcing all of them to be `character` class, no longer numbers. If you are doing this for report generation, then that's fine, but otherwise you are corrupting your data. While it's possible to convert a string to a number, it is not always a perfect reversal, so doing this unnecessarily should be avoided.
4. I'm going to assume that having `NA`s in the data is just as bad (for your needs) as having `NaN`s, so fixing #3 by replacing with `NA` is not fixing the problem. If you are still going to be doing calculations on the data, then you should keep them as numbers, and many (not all) number-calculating functions allow an argument `na.rm=TRUE` so that the `NA` and `NaN` values do not kill the calcs.

   ```r
   sum(c(1,NA))
   # [1] NA
   sum(c(1,NaN))
   # [1] NaN
   sum(c(1,NaN), na.rm=T)
   # [1] 1
   ```

   For those calculations that don't have that option, how to fix it depends on what is being done. If it's an aggregating function, then you can use `na.omit`, as a call of `sum(na.omit(c(1,NaN)))`, equivalent to those in #3. If not, then you might be able to use `ifelse(is.na(.), yes=, no=)` to vary your calcs. (One note on this, the `yes` and `no` vectors are still calculated completely, so you might still get warnings. What `ifelse` gives us is allows us to choose specific values from each vector to be the overall return.)

Comment: thanks I am at the point where I am changing the NA NaN and so forth for display purposes and not doing any calculation.  As suggested I get around the such values with na.omit, na,rm=T where appropriate.  My NoNA function works over a list of dataframes, however, my NoNaN does not.  I have tried implementing a few different ways such as with lapply as you suggested but without success.  This is more of a nice to have as Its a regular occurrence than something that is preventing me from doing my work

Comment: If you have `LOF`, a list of frames, then you need a double-map, perhaps `map(LOF, ~ map(., NoNA))`? (Your `NoNaN` function as written is still broken, in case you haven't fixed the incorrect `x[is.nan]`.)